# Transition Effect not rendering on website

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-hooks, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I tried to include the TranisitionEffect component in my pages but it is not appearing on the website.

I am trying to create a transition effect which appears upon changing the pages of the website. Here is my code for TransitionEffect.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';

const TransitionEffect = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <motion.div
        className='fixed top-0 bottom-0 right-full w-screen h-screen z-30 bg-primary'
        initial={{ x: '100%', width: '100%' }}
        animate={{ x: '0%', width: '0%' }}
        exit={{ x: ['0%', '100%'], width: ['0%', '100%'] }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.8, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
      />
      <motion.div
        className='fixed top-0 bottom-0 right-full w-screen h-screen z-20 bg-light'
        initial={{ x: '100%', width: '100%' }}
        animate={{ x: '0%', width: '0%' }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.2, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
      />
      <motion.div
        className='fixed top-0 bottom-0 right-full w-screen h-screen z-10 bg-dark'
        initial={{ x: '100%', width: '100%' }}
        animate={{ x: '0%', width: '0%' }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.4, ease: 'easeInOut' }}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default TransitionEffect;
```

Here is my code for index.js and how I have included the TransitionEffect component:

```
import Head from "next/head";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";
import ContainerBlock from "../components/ContainerBlock";
import FavouriteProjects from "../components/FavouriteProjects";
import LatestCode from "../components/LatestCode";
import Hero from "../components/Hero";
import Spinner from "../components/Spinner"
import  TransitionEffect from "../components/TransitionEffect";
import getLatestRepos from "@lib/getLatestRepos";
import userData from "@constants/data";

export default function Home({ repositories }) {
  return (
    <>
      <TransitionEffect />
      <ContainerBlock
        title="Aryan Kapoor - Student, Developer and Designer"
        description="I've embarked on this journey as a CS major. Feel free to reach out to me."
      >
        <Hero />
        <Spinner />
        <LatestCode repositories={repositories} />
      </ContainerBlock>
    </>
  );
}


export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  console.log(process.env.GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN);
  let token = process.env.GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN;

  const repositories = await getLatestRepos(userData, token);
  // console.log("REPOSITORIES", repositories);

  return {
    props: {
      repositories,
    },
  };
};

  /*<FavouriteProjects />*/
```

Similarly I have the code for other pages where I have included the TransitionEffect component for example,Projects.js:

```
import React from "react";
import ContainerBlock from "../components/ContainerBlock";
import Projects from "../components/Projects";
import TransitionEffect from "../components/TransitionEffect";

export default function projects() {
  return (
    <>
      <TransitionEffect />
      <ContainerBlock title="Projects - Aryan Kapoor">
        <Projects />
      </ContainerBlock>
    </>
  );
}
```

What seems to be the issue here, could someone please help me out?